# mobile compatible map markers

Tags: html, css

I placed an image of a map and put two little markers on it (I replaced them simply with letters for the time being). The issue is, that on the mobile view they are totally in a different position than on desktop view.

Can some please explain me how can I resolve this issue and why did it happen?

```
<html>
    <body>
    <style>
    .container{
      width: 70%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
    }
    #map > img{
     max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 100%;
    }
    .marker{
     height: 1.5em;
     font-size: 10px;
     width: 1.5em;
     position: absolute;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    .europe{
     top: 25%;
     left: 50%;
    }
    .canada{
     top: 25%;
     left: 25%;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="map">
          <img src="https://linmark.com/assets/site/images/network/map.png" />
          <div class="marker europe">A</div>
          <div class="marker canada">B</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to make the markers appear on the same place on both mobile view and desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `transform:translate` to keep the markers "centered" in their original positions.

Recall, your elements are a *fixed* size but your positioning and image is % based.

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#map>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.marker {
  height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* this */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.europe {
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
}

.canada {
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="map">
    <img src="http://linmark.com/assets/site/images/network/map.png" />
    <div class="marker europe">A</div>
    <div class="marker canada">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rGxeEm)